# Android Native Debugging: "Please run build/tools/build-platforms.sh to build the corresponding directory."

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk

I'm getting the following error when trying to debug my android application as Native.
I'm running on Windows. I select Debug As->Android Native Application

**"Could not find platform files (headers and libraries)
Please run build/tools/build-platforms.sh to build the corresponding directory."**

Yes: My NDK path is setup in Eclipse->Preferences.

YES: The NDK and SDK path's are setup in the PATH env var.

After searching the web for a solution, I came accross the init.mk file that creates the error but I wasn't able to devise a solution. build-platforms.sh doesn't exist. **It looks like perhaps NDK_ROOT isn't getting set by whatevers calling the build process?**

```
The platform files were moved in the Android source tree from
$TOP/ndk/build/platforms to $TOP/development/ndk/platforms. However,
the official NDK release packages still place them under the old
location for now, so deal with this here
NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT := $(strip $(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT))

    ifndef NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT
    NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT := $(strip $(wildcard $(NDK_ROOT)/platforms))
    ifndef NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT
    NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT := $(strip $(wildcard $(NDK_ROOT)/build/platforms))
    endif

    ifndef NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT
    $(call __ndk_info,Could not find platform files (headers and libraries))
    $(if $(strip $(wildcard $(NDK_ROOT)/RELEASE.TXT)),\
        $(call __ndk_info,Please define NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT to point to a valid directory.)\
    ,\
        $(call __ndk_info,Please run build/tools/build-platforms.sh to build the corresponding directory.)\
    )
    $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
    endif

    $(call ndk_log,Found platform root directory: $(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT))
endif
```

Comment: I read that build-platforms.sh is actually named gen-platforms.sh; I'm having the problem as well and investigating.